# How to get previous route name (pattern) in Fat Free Framework?

Tags: php, routes, fat-free-framework

I'm trying to create simple language switcher for my site on Fat Free Framework. My logic is next:

1. Create route /lang/@lang
2. Inside the route set the language form PARAM.lang
3. Reroute user to the same page

The main issue for me – how to get that previous page route name? 
I'll be appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track the previous page URL somehow. Here are 2 ways to do it:

- add the current page URI to the lang switcher link, as a query string: `/lang/@lang?uri={{ urlencode(@URI) }}`
- rely on the referer URL specified by the browser: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Since this value is not 100 % reliable and may even not be set at all, you should make a quick check of its relevancy (same domain?) before using it, and fallback on the homepage otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use you first way and it definitely works! :)